# How can I transform two dimension array to graph or to adjacency matrix?

Tags: javascript, graph, adjacency-matrix

I need to find neighbours and write them to graph or to adjacency matrix
I have input data:

```
[ 
    [ '.', 'X', '.' ], 
    [ '.', 'X', '.' ], 
    [ '.', '.', '.' ] 
]
```

Example of Matrix:
[image]

I tried to initialize matrix and make two nested for loop.

```
const matrix = Array(length*length).fill(Array(length*length).fill(0))
```

Example of graph:
[image]

Comment: please add some data and wanted result of it. what have you tried?

Comment: ok, so what problems do you have in your current implementation? We will not provide one for you :)

Comment: As for my trying. I tried transform input data by for loop inside for loop. It had nothing, so it makes no sense to share. I think I chose wrong path of solving the problem. Wanted result is object Map(I shared the screenshot)